# Sql Server - connect with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

i must connect to a sql server with windows authentication

sql server is on machine 192.168.3.6
web server (client) is on my machine 192.168.3.10

I'm using JTDS driver

```
dbUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.3.6:1099/db_test;instance=test
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( dbUrl, "", "" );
```

I have username and password of administrator user of sql server !

I also put `ntlmauth.dll` into `c:\windows` and `c:\windows\system32` and I have always error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not
>   associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

Any idea to solve my problem ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See jTDS FAQ http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

you will have to pass `useNTLMv2=true` and `domain=yourdomain`

Comment: Wonderfull, I have resolved

dbUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.3.6:1099/db_test;instance=test;useNTLMv2=true;domain=workgroup
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( dbUrl, dbUser, dbPwd )

I must use parameters useNTLMv2=true and domain. The value of parameter domain is no important. It works also with domain=pippo !! I do not know how .....:-)

Comment: Any ideas as to why this would work with TC but not with DBVisualizer with exact same parms ?

Comment: I did not see addressed the issue of entering a password for a connection string; seems to have been sidestepped. Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is something like:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MYPC/MYDB;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Make sure you have jtds.jar in the Java build path.

Also, add "-Djava.library.path="PATH\JTDS\x64\SSO" where 'Path' is where your SSO folder is after installing the JTDS driver (this is where you have your ntlmauth.dll).

[Here](http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java/) is a short step-by-step guide showing how to connect to SQL Server using jTDS (as well as JDBC) with Windows authentication should you need more details. Hope it helps!