# SonarQube with sqlserver trusted connection

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

How can we setup sonarqube with Sql-server trusted connection mode. I am setting up sonarqube 5.0.1 and it is straight forward with sql server authentication mode i.e.  change sonar properties file with sql server user name and pwd

Can anyone shed some light ?

Comment: You might want to have a try with the indication provided on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication

Comment: @Mithfindel: I have tried mentioned approach before I post question. connection string change with latest NTLMAuth file did not work for me.

Comment: Did you every figure this out? I'm stumped as well

Comment: @Mike, Mentioned approach in first comment did not work for you ?  I did not get it worked though.  I am using sql server authentication as of now.

Comment: Nope. I was unable to get it working. I spent almost a day on it and gave up.