# Integrated security with JDBC sonarQube is failing with error while connecting with sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, sonarqube

I am trying to use Integrated security with JDBC connection and I kept following two properties as commented  but still its saying it is using 'sonar' as username and password. 
sonar.jdbc.username
sonar.jdbc.password

I tried to give my windows user name and password but still not working. I went through other posts but didnt help much.

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682900/229031

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server - connect with windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication)