# Windows authentication with JDBC and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds, mssql-jdbc

I need to connect using JDBC to SQL Server using Windows Authentication where I provide username and password from the connection String. Is this possible with Windows Authentication?

I have tried this with both JTDS and msql-jdbc but can't get it to work

```
private  Connection getDBConnection() {
  Connection dbConnection = null;
  try {
         System.out.println("load driver");
         Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
         log.info("loaded");

         String con = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://PNT00-PMP-SQL01:1433/iceware;domain=workgroup;userName=user;password=password";

         dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(con);

         log.info("got connection");

        return dbConnection;

   } catch (Exception e) {
         log.error(e.getMessage());
   }
   return dbConnection;
 }
```

I have tried various combinations for the username and domain but usually get something like:

019-01-18 14:15:31 ERROR com.pts.demo.service.JdbcService - Login failed for user '/'. ClientConnectionId:962eeab5-226c-4f85-9911-644a570529ab

Any help much appreciated

Comment: If you use Windows authentication you don't have to supply username and password.

Comment: integratedSecurity=true property?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a Windows client or some other platform?

Comment: a windows client

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the properties in the connection string `useNTLMv2=true` and `domain=yourdomain`

This may be duplicate : [Sql Server - connect with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication)

There is also another way - https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java/

Also you can try the below code to get SQL JDBC connection (username & password are provided in the props files instead of specifying them on the connection string)

```
............
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.10.101:1433/dbName;charset=utf8";
System.setProperty("jsse.enableCBCProtection", "false"); // for SSL enabled MSSQL
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.put("user",user);
prop.put("password",passWord);
prop.put("domain",domain);
prop.put("useNTLMv2","true");

dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl , prop);
........
```

Comment: Thanks< I will give this a try tomorrow, unfortunately, I am dependent on remote access to the site and I can't get access until tomorrow

Comment: I tried that I first got an error "Native SSPI library not loaded.". I downloaded the "ntlmauth.dll" for JTDS 1.3.0 and placed it in the JAVA\Bin folder and ran the jar again. And now I get  I/O Error: DB server closed connection. This implies to me a config issue on the server and not an authentication error. Is that correct?

Comment: I have overcome my immediate problem by getting mixed mode Authentication enabled on the DB and using a SQL user to access. I would still like to know if it possible to use Windows Auth and provide user credentials via the connection string or at least some other means than the logged in user

Comment: @gtfisher27 - updated the answer , please check this works on your environment.

Comment: I would not recommend the use of jTDS anymore. There were no updates to the project since 2013. That means it does not officially support Sql server 2014 and up.