# SymmetricDS Community Edition passwords hard-coding in property files

Tags: passwords, symmetricds, property-files, hard-coding

We have setup SymmetricDS on Windows for SQL server databases and it's working fine.
But we have hard-coded the passwords in property files. My question here is, is there any way to avoid hard-coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt your passwords.

https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.12/html/user-guide.html#_encrypted_passwords

Answer (score 0):

If you set SQL-Server to use Windows authentication for the SymmetricDS user, then you can leave the db.user and db.password properties empty.

[Sql Server - connect with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682852/sql-server-connect-with-windows-authentication)

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Just a query...Do all users need to have windows authentication or only SymmetricDS user which currently is being used in property files?

Comment: You probably have SQL-Server in mixed mode, so you can set each user to use either Windows authentication or SQL-Server authentication.  You only need to affect the SymmetricDS user to use Windows authentication.